# How to move files to different folders based on their prefix?

Tags: bash, awk, mv

- I have thousands of files in my home folder that look like this:

```
> ls 

6_2_S28_R1_001.fastq.gz  
19_1_S160_R1_001.fastq.gz
25_3_S114_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

- Here, as an example, I break down the name of the file 6_2_S28_R1_001.fastq.gz; 
  6_ = day6 
  2_ = replicate 2  
  S28_R1_001.fastq.gz = extension
- In the same directory I have the folders

```
rep1
rep2
rep3
```

**My goal**

I am trying to move each file to a different folder based on the prefix, that is related to the replicate

```
6_2_S28_R1_001.fastq.gz,   #this file needs to be moved to rep2 <br>
19_1_S160_R1_001.fastq.gz, #this file needs to be moved to rep1 <br>
25_3_S114_R1_001.fastq.gz, #thus file needs to go to rep3 folder <br>
```

I have tried an unsuccessful for loop.
Any help or guidance are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for f in *_*_*_*_*.gz; do
    i="${f#*_}"; i="${i%%_*}"
    d="rep$i"
    echo "Move '$f' to '$d'"
    mkdir -p "$d" \
    && mv "$f" "$d"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Arnaud! One silly question what is the %% stand for

Comment: `man bash` said about # and ## patterns : Remove  matching  prefix  pattern
and about % and %% : Remove  matching  suffix  pattern.
Use bash patterns is really faster than `cut`, `tr`, and many other commands